# How did they see the effects of the superweapon in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

> So, they have the Starkiller. Big bang, faster than lightspeed superweapon that blows up planets. Ok. Fine.

But how do they see it?

> The good guys are standing on the surface of a planet and look up and see the big red glow and boom.

So were they in the same solar as the target? Was there some other effect letting them see it at FTL speeds? Has no-one making the film heard of the speed of light?

Comment: Yep, clear dupe. I tried searching before hand but that question must have been too cryptic in spoiler avoidance to hit my search :(

Comment: Believe it or not, even though the title on mine used to be "How did characters see this event happen in The Force Awakens" and the body was all spoilertext, someone _still_ complained about spoilers after I posted it.